# what's correct: var declaration if undefined

Tags: javascript

I have heard different opinions about the usage of `var` at a situation like this:

```
function(maybeUndefined) {
    if(typeof maybeUndefined === 'undefined')
        var maybeUndefined = 'bob';
}
```

Is it necessary to notate `var`, or not, because `maybeUndefined` is an `argument` of `function`?

Comment: You use `this` word; I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: Yes, the parameter name already makes it a local variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need the `var` in this case, as `mayBeUndefined` is already allocated within the scope of the function (hint: listing argument variables in a function definition causes those variables to be declared locally). That `var` is therefore completely optional, though completely pointless (and a drain on readability).

Comment: What do you mean by "the function definition casts it"?

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus [citation needed]? Are you writing a paper?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: `function(a,b,c)` implies the presence of `a`,`b` and `c` as local variables within the function.

Comment: @RienNeVaPlus It's specified here: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5 Parameters are added to the function's environment in step 4. d. IV.

Comment: @Mathletics: no, I just want to create the best answerpage for guys like me googling this stuff :)

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Sime was commenting on your _curious_ use of __casts__.

Comment: @Mathletics: hopefully improved.

Comment: Better, though wordy; the word you were looking for is __declared__. Your answer is correct either way.

Comment: _"though not harmful"_ - I wold suggest that it is a _bit_ harmful, because anything that makes the code harder to read makes maintenance more difficult.

Answer (score 6):

Example:

```
function func ( arg1, arg2 ) {
    var local1, local2;

    function nested1 () {}
    function nested2 () {}

    // other code
}
```

Here we have a function declaration. When this declaration is parsed into a function object, a lexical environment (= scope) is created for that function with the following bindings:

- arg1
- arg2
- local1
- local2
- nested1
- nested2
- this
- arguments

(Notice how there also are two special, built-in bindings: `this` and `arguments`. These are always created for all function objects.)

These names are defined as local bindings. (This process is specified in ["Declaration binding instantiation"](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5). Warning: this algorithm is not meant to be read by humans `:-)`) Therefore, when a name is defined as a parameter, it is not necessary to declare it as a local variable. This mechanism is independent of whether a value (argument) is passed for that parameter when the function is invoked.

So, even if you invoke the function like so:

```
func(123);
```

the name `arg2` will still be defined (as a binding in the function's environment), although its value will initially be `undefined` for that particular invocation.

Btw, if you use the *strict language* (recommended!), function environments are **static** which means that the above bindings are garanteed to be the only bindings in the function's environment. The *default language*, on the other hand, provides certain mechanisms to, **dynamically**, add/remove bindings from the function's environment. Example:

```
(function () {

    // the name "temp" does not exist as a binding in the function's environment

    eval('var temp');

    // now it does

    delete temp;

    // and it's gone again

}());
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `var` again, it is bad for readability, and the variable will already be scoped locally as a result of being an argument.

Also, you should note that it is not a part of `this`. `this` will only be scoped to the function object if the `new` keyword has been used, and as you do not have a named function, that seems unlikely in this case. Without new, `this` refers to window (or is `undefined` if `use strict;` is used), of which your variable is definitely not a part of as a result of the argument having a local scope.

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to the _scope_ of the function even with `new`. And without `new` there are several ways to call the function such that `this` will not be `window`.

Comment: In the strict language (which should be the implied language, IMO), `this` is `undefined` for regular function invocations. So, not the global object.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Added a note referencing `use strict;`.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Corrected the reference to `this` with regards to scope.

Answer (score 1):

**Interfacing**

Including a function argument is effectively the same as scoping a variable (in other words, it's effectively the same thing as defining a function-level reference using the **`var`** keyword). The main reason for providing function arguments (in JavaScript) is for your own interfacing preference.

**The `arguments` object**

Arguments may still be passed to functions without parameters, and will still be accessible in the 'hidden' `arguments` object -- which is sort of a "pseudo-array" (if you will), in that it is functionally an array, but is not equipped with the same APIs JavaScript equips the `Array` (pseudo-type) with:

```
// The following functions do the same thing, but one is "more readable"

function foo() {
  return arguments;
}

function bar(baz, qux) {
  return arguments;
}
```

**Evaluation (interface) vs Execution (implement)**

When both functions are *evaluated* (on file 'load'), the `arguments` object is `undefined` in every function definition; the object doesn't become "defined" until the function *body* executes the code therein; to *visualize* that using pseudo-code, it'd look something like this:

```
// Function bodies (as objects)
foo : {
  arguments : new Array // [undefined]
  __proto__ : Empty() // the super-object that allows this object to inherit "functionality"
}

bar : {
  arguments : new Array(baz, qux) // [undefined, undefined]
  __proto__ : Empty()
}
```

**Function invocation**

So when you invoke a function, it "implements" or "executes" its *body* (its "object"). When it does that, if the objects that have been pushed into the **`arguments`** object are defined, then the function can reference them. If not, a reference error will be thrown, logging that the variables are `undefined` in that scope.

**In short:**

It isn't necessary to interface function-scope-level variables (aka "private members") using **`var`** because the language already attaches the `arguments` object to all `function` body objects.

**More reading:**

JavaScript Memoization: "Function-caching" multiple arguments for better performance: 
http://decodize.com/javascript/javascript-memoization-caching-results-for-better-performance/

Comment: Note that `arguments` is *not* actually of the JavaScript type "Array" -- I used it for illustration purposes, because they're so similar (one extends the other). But `arguments` is of the abstract data type "array" (structurally) in that it is a *vector* which carries a "sequence" of elements; the "Empty" function set on an object's `prototype` is so that JavaScript can *necessarily* implement that object's `constructor` (or "execute its {body}"). There's a lot of good reading on StackOverflow about objects, prototypes, and constructors; and their effect on/affect by the reference scope.